# How to test for mean and variance both affected by a variable?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

Suppose you observe $\left(x_i,y_i\right)$, where $y_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2\right)$. There are a number of ways that the $\mu_i, \sigma_i$ might vary with $x_i$:

1. If one suspected $\mu_i$ varied with $x_i$, but $\sigma_i$ is independent of $x_i$, one could perform plain old linear regression.
2. If one suspected $\sigma_i$ varied with $x_i$, a heteroskedasticity test (*e.g.* Breusch-Pagan) could be performed.

I am interested in a third case where ${\mu_i}/{\sigma_i}$ vary linearly with $x_i$, but there is no correlation assumed between $\mu_i$ and $x_i$, and no correlation assumed between $\sigma_i$ and $x_i$. Is there a standard test for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The term $\mu_i/\sigma_i$ seems to be the inverse of the [coefficient of variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation). In [this](http://www.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/imperia/md/content/mathematik3/publications/dewie4.pdf) paper, the authors test whether the coefficient of variation is constant in nonparametric models.

Comment: Nice find; Unfortunately, the CV has a discontinuity when $\mu = 0$, which is a real possibility in my application.